# Multithreading, why is this serial code faster than its parallel version?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm trying my hand at some multithreading in cpp11 and cannot figure out why in the following code, the serial version is much faster than the parallel one.

I understand that in this minimal example, the compute function is not worth parallelizing, but I'd like to use a similar approach to parallelize pixel rendering in a RayTracing algorithm, in which the compute takes much longer, but I get the same difference in duration in that other case.

I guess I'm missing something about threads. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

void compute(double& res)
{
    res = 2*res;
}

void computeSerial(std::vector<double>& res, const size_t& nPoints)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
    {
        compute(res[i]);
    }
}

void computeParallel(std::vector<double>& res, const size_t& nPoints)
{
    int numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
    std::vector<std::thread*> pool(numThreads, nullptr);
    size_t nPointsComputed = 0;
    while(nPointsComputed < nPoints)
    {
        size_t firstIndex = nPointsComputed;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            size_t index = firstIndex + i;
            if(index < nPoints)
            {
                pool[i] = new std::thread(compute, std::ref(res[index]));
            }
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            size_t index = firstIndex + i;
            if(index < nPoints)
            {
                pool[i]->join();
                delete pool[i];
            }
        }
        nPointsComputed += numThreads;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t pbSize = 1000;
    std::vector<double> vSerial(pbSize, 0);
    std::vector<double> vParallel(pbSize, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pbSize; i++)
    {
        vSerial[i] = i;
        vParallel[i] = i;
    }

    int numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << "Number of threads: " << numThreads << std::endl;

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin, end;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    computeSerial(vSerial, pbSize);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "duration serial   = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ns]" << std::endl;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    computeParallel(vParallel, pbSize);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "duration parallel = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ns]" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Afer compilation with `clang++ -pthread main.cc` I get the following output:

```
Number of threads: 6
duration serial   = 23561[µs]
duration parallel = 12219928[µs]
```

The serial version is consistantly much faster than the parallel one, no matter the number of doubles to compute.

Comment: µs is the abbreviation for microseconds, but you are casting to nanoseconds. This matters as 12,219,928 nanoseconds is 12 milliseconds which is a reasonable amount of time to create 6 threads, whereas 12,219,928 microseconds is 12 seconds, which is not.

Answer (score 4):

Starting a thread (or even just doing a dynamic allocation) is something that requires a lot more instructions that computing the double of a number.

You need to split your job in bigger chunks... starting a separate CPU thread just to compute `2*x` will never be an optimization.

It could make sense to split the job of computing the double of 4000000 numbers in 4 threads, with each of them computing 1000000 results in a loop.

Things are very different for GPUs, where for example running a thread for each pixel is ok.

Comment: Its as you explained, the "starting" a thread. With respect to the remark that "running a thread for a single pixel is OK on the GPU": Although CPU and GPU are different in some aspects (like MIMD vs SIMD), *starting* a thread is expensive on the GPU too and pushing data to a *running* thread may be fine on the CPU.

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense, I just tested it and got the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you are creating 1000 threads, and not 6 threads, because in your line

```
nPointsComputed += numThreads;
```

increments by number of threads and the loop runs to nPointsComputed < 1000.

Instead you have to

- create batches of `numberOfPointsPerThread = numberOfPoints / numberOfThreads`,
- then create `numberOfThreads` threads, each working on a batch of size `numberOfPointsPerThread` with an offset, that is thread `i` works on the `indices k = i * numberOfPointsPerThread, ..., (i+1)*numberOfPointsPerThread-1`.

You have to be careful if the devision numberOfPoints / numberOfThreads has a remainder. Use a ceil function to create larger batches and limit the last batch to the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you, based on both your answers I got it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating/ Deallocating threads is very time consuming, because the kernel has lot of things to do for the context changes.
This is why it is better to use ONE thread on each core, and a fifo in which you feeds many tasks that will be dispatched across running threads .

Have a look at this code :
https://github.com/sancelot/thread_pool